# Discord.py- Give role to a user

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to give a user a role using the discord.py, but I keep getting the same error.
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: role is a required argument that is missing.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord
import methods

# Intents
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

# Object for discord
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
TOKEN = 'active_token'

channel_name = 'ladder'
role_name = 'Ladder Participant'
```

```
@bot.command()
async def join_ladder(ctx, role: discord.Role, user: discord.Member):
    """
    This command lets you join the ladder.

    !join_ladder
    """

    if methods.check_ladder_active(): # Method returns True or False
        role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name=role_name)
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send('You are now apart of the ladder.')
        # ADD USERS NAME TO ACTUAL LADDER
    else:
        await ctx.send('Ladder is inactive.')


@bot.command()
async def leave_ladder(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    """
    This command lets you leave the ladder:

    !leave_ladder
    """
    if methods.check_ladder_active():
        role = ctx.guild.get_role('1055287896376082463')  # add role id
        await user.remove_roles(role)
        await ctx.send('You are no longer apart of the ladder.')
        # REMOVE USER FROM LADDER FILE
    else:
        ctx.send('Ladder is inactive')
```

I have tried two different ways of giving the user the role, the !join_ladder is the most recent way I've tried and the !leave_ladder was the first way but instead of user.remove_roles(role) it was user.add_roles(role).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your commands have required arguments that you didn't provide when calling them, like this command:

```py
async def join_ladder(ctx, role: discord.(Role, user: discord.Member):
```

The `role` and `user` arguments are required, so when you're just calling the command like this `(prefix) join_ladder`, discord.py cannot find the required arguments because they're missing. The most simple way to fix this is to just remove the arguments that you're not using in your function or provide them when using the command.

```py
async def join_ladder(ctx, user: discord.Member):
```

[Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters) is an relevant example.

Also, I see that you have both `discord.Client` and `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instance, please pick one of them and remove the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, this is my new code for anyone wondering.

@bot.command()
async def join_ladder(ctx):
"""
This command lets you join the ladder.

```
!join_ladder
"""

if methods.check_ladder_active(): # Method returns True or False
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role_name)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send('You are now apart of the ladder.')
    # ADD USERS NAME TO ACTUAL LADDER
else:
    await ctx.send('Ladder is inactive.')
```